Multicolor Ramsey Number - prove lower bound
Prove lower bound $R(3, n, m) > 2 R(n, m) - 2$ where $m, n > 2$
I guess if we wanna prove that $R(3, n, m) > N$ we need to show an example of construction that would have $N$ vertices and would not match the definition.
But I can't come up with such an example

If n,m are both 3, we have R(3,3,3)<=17>10

Hints:
Let $\ell:=R(m,n) - 1$. We want to exhibit a coloring of $K_{2\ell}$ with no green $K_3$, no red $K_m$, and no blue $K_n$. Consider two disjoint copies of $K_{\ell}$. For edges between these two copies, color them green. For edges within each copy, use a red/blue coloring with no red $K_m$ and no blue $K_n$ (why should this exist?).

what do you mean by "For each copy of ℓ
, color the edges the same way, and use only red/blue edges.", what is "the same way"? if you mean that we should use red & blue colors they can not be colored the same way as we did with green edges because they have different colors

do you mean that we should color all edges inside of each $K_l$ copy in red & blue colors and there won't be red $K_m$ or blue $K_n$ because there are only $R(n, m) - 1$ vertices in each copy and we won't have enough (missing 1 vertex) to use definition of ramsey number on these copies to find $K_n, K_m$?

I mean that we use the same coloring for both copies of $K_l$: if we label the vertices of both copies of $K_l$ $1, \dots, l$, then if in one copy edge $ij$ has color red, the other copy should have color red as well. Green edges are for edges between the two copies of $K_l$, red/blue edges are for edges within each $K_l$. And yes, the red/blue coloring used should be the coloring that doesn't give a red $K_m$ or a blue $K_n$, which will exist by definition of $l$.

Edited for clarity.
